# IF-statement stroke in a line diagram using d3.js

Tags: javascript, if-statement, d3.js, svg, attr

I've drawn a graph using data out of a database, and I want that line to turn red when the number in the database gets higher than 500 (like below). Unfortunately it doesn't work this way, and I've tried some other stuff, but no succes.

Though a dashed line does work using the code `.style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))`

My question: Is it possible to let the stroke color turn red when the y value gets higher than a certain point in d3.js?

```
// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")                                 // Explicitly state where the svg element will go on the web page (the 'body')
    .append("svg")                                          // Append 'svg' to the html 'body' of the web page
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)  // Set the 'width' of the svg element
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)// Set the 'height' of the svg element
    .append("g")                                            // Append 'g' to the html 'body' of the web page
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); // in a place that is the actual area for the graph

d3.json("php/data2.php", function(error, data) {            // Go to the data folder (in the current directory) and read in the data.tsv file
    data.forEach(function(d) {                              // For all the data values carry out the following
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);                         // Parse the date from a set format (see parseDate)
        d.close = +d.close;                                 // makesure d.close is a number, not a string
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));      // set the x domain so be as wide as the range of dates we have.
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);   // set the y domain to go from 0 to the maximum value of d.close

// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")                                      // append the valueline line to the 'path' element
    .attr("class", "line")                              // apply the 'line' CSS styles to this path
    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
    .attr("d", valueline(data));                        // call the 'valueline' finction to draw the line

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")                                         // append the x axis to the 'g' (grouping) element
    .attr("class", "x axis")                            // apply the 'axis' CSS styles to this path
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")   // move the drawing point to 0,height
    .call(xAxis);                                       // call the xAxis function to draw the axis

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")                                         // append the y axis to the 'g' (grouping) element
    .attr("class", "y axis")                            // apply the 'axis' CSS styles to this path
    .call(yAxis);                                       // call the yAxis function to draw the axis
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is probably not binded correctly to your element, but it's difficult to tell without the complete code. You probably need...

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")                                    
    .attr("class", "line")                              
    .attr("stroke", function(d) {..});
```

You can see a simplified demonstration of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/V84Fz/

Comment: Don't forget `.attr("d", valueline)`. And `.data(data)` needs to be `.data([data])`.